# why does zod make all my fields optional when using infer?

Tags: typescript, zod

Hi guys I am running into this issue where zod is making all my fields optional when using `z.infer` this is the types. it is declared in a types package that imports the validators from a validators package

```
import type { z } from 'zod';
import type { cardValidator, imageBlockValidator, textBlockValidator } from 'validators';

export type ValidatedCard = z.infer<typeof cardValidator>;
export type ValidatedTextBlock = z.infer<typeof textBlockValidator>;
export type ValidatedImageBlock = z.infer<typeof imageBlockValidator>;
```

this package is not compiled but just in case I added a `tsconfig.json` with `strict` set to `true`, I am importing the type in another package called `utils` and this is the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Default",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "preserveWatchOutput": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

this is a base config and is imported through extends but just in case I added it to the local config as well but still no difference

I saw this problem here before and it was always resolved by setting `strict` to `true` but for some reason in my case this doesn't seem to work, I can't compile my apps since i am passing optional values to functions and variables that require strings etc...

typescript version `^4.9.3`

zod version in both validators and types packages `^3.20.2`

Edit: [here is the validator file](https://hastebin.com/share/qegenehobu.php) I figured it might be too long to put in here

Comment: Does it return optional fields for `z.object({ username: z.string() });`? If yes, you can put that in your question to make it clear it does not depend on how `cardValidator` looks like. If no, please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the relevant parts in your question

Comment: This is almost definitely an issue with the things you're inferring the types of (`cardValidator`, etc), not your configuration options. If you can post the code for any of those that would help.

Comment: @A_A yes every property even nested ones are optional I edited my post to include a link to a hastebin with the validators

Comment: @AdamCoster I added a link with a modified validator that does the same thing

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it locally (e.g. it showed me that `name` for ValidatedCard is mandatory). Can you try to make a minimal reproducible example (smallest amount of code necessary to produce the optional parameters error)? This could include: trying it with an object with only one field instead of 3 objects with each 10+ fields; trying to import it from a file in the same package; trying to not import it at all and instead put the `cardValidator` declaration into the same package; trying it in a new project with only zod installed as npm dependency

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with `zod` per se, you need to set `"strictNullChecks": true` in tsconfig.json like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...other options
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    ...other options
  },
}
```